# I got stuck on following c programming, did not understend output

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char source[]="Sayonara";
    char target[8];
    strcpy(target,source);
    printf("source string= %s\n",source);
    printf("target string= %s\n",target);
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:-     source string=
             target string=Sayonara

Comment: You are copying 9 bytes into an 8 byte array `target`. It's undefined behaviour, so anything can happen.

Comment: Are you sure about output?

Comment: i want to know control flow of this programm.

Comment: C is pretty much a *sequential* language, the code you have goes from the top to the bottom. That's the flow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The length of `source` is 9, because it has a null-terminator `\0`. You are copying beyond the bounds of `target`, which invokes *undefined behaviour*.

You need to make `target` the same length or longer to ensure it is null-terminated after the copy and no out of bounds access occurs.

```
char source[]="Sayonara";
char target[9];
strcpy(target,source);
```

Answer (score 3):

After copying `source` to `target`, `target` is not null terminated. Since `strcpy` copies up to the first null character (`'\0'`), it will continue copying past the end of the array `target` as it short by one in length than the `source` array. This will invoke undefined behavior.

```
char target[8];
```

to

```
char target[9];
```

Comment: i know but what is control flow ???

Comment: Wikipedia explains what is the [control flow graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow_graph)... the [control flow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow) is moving on that graph.

Comment: @Harishkumar; Do you want to know about cyclomatic complexity of that program?